# Django auth behaving crazy or am i getting it wrong?

Tags: django-views

I have this user 'u' when i try :

```
In [4]: u.get_all_permissions()
Out[4]: {u'jctracker.supervisor_dashboard'}
```

but when i try :

```
In [5]: u.has_perm(u,"jctracker.supervisor_dashboard")
Out[5]: False
```

what going wrong here? this problem is not letting in an user "u" to pass permission_required decorator

help please!!

Comment: i know nothing about django but do you really need that `u` as the first param to `u.has_perm`?

Answer (score 0):

has_perm receives permission as first argument, so you just need to remove 'u' from your function call:

```
u.has_perm("jctracker.supervisor_dashboard")
```